# Using fread() to select rows and columns, the way read.csv.sql() does

Tags: r, data.table

I know `fread` is relatively new, but it really gives great performance improvements. What I want to know is, can you select rows and columns from the file that you are reading? A bit like what `read.csv.sql` does? I know using the `select` option of the `fread` one can select the columns to read, but how about reading only the rows which satisfy a certain criteria.

For example, can something like below be implemented using `fread`?

```
read.csv.sql(file, sql = "select V2,V4,V7,V8,V9, V10 from file where V5=='CE' and V10 >= 500",header = FALSE, sep= '|', eol ="\n")
```

If this is not possible yet, is it advisable to read the entire lot of data, and then use `subset` etc to arrive at the final result? Or will it defeat the purpose of using `fread`?

For reference, I have to read about 800 files, each containing about 100,000 rows and 10 columns.
Any input is welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Eventually, yes. Just need to add the filename as a column in each file read. Then combine all into one big file.

Comment: The documentation isn't mentioning such a function. Moreover, when the selection of rows has to meet certain criteria (which are, I suppose, based on the info in the df's), you have to read the data first .....

Comment: I'd do: `ans = rbindlist(lapply(files, function(x) fread(x)[, fn := x]))`. Then, subset once on `ans` (assuming the subset criteria is the same).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Could you please explain what you are doing here? I am not that well-versed with R as yet :)

Comment: @Arun I figured this out, and it is an excellent approach. The only problem is that as the files are huge, I cant read them all in one go. In fact, just reading 10 files ate up close to 1.5 GB of my available RAM. So I have to resort to a loop to read a few files at a time, subset them and then clear the memory. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I have the same question as shivam has. Does anyone know if it will be possible with fread in the near future?

Comment: @user1983395 For me it worked once I followed Arun's approach and used the workaround that I commented. You may want to give it a try.

Comment: @Shivam could you answer your question and mark it as answered than? just to remove it from the list of open questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to select rows with `fread()` as with `read.csv.sql()` yet. But it is still better to read the entire data (memory permitting) and then subset it as per your criteria. For a 200 mb file, `fread()`+ `subset()` gave ~ 4 times better performance than `read.csv.sql()`.

So, using @Arun's suggestion,

```
ans = rbindlist(lapply(files, function(x) fread(x)[, fn := x]))
subset(ans, 'your criteria')
```

is better than the approach in the original question.